# Creating a filled rectangle with WINAPI

Tags: windows, winapi

I have created a window using the Win32 API, with a painted Text and a Button. If the button is pressed, it will be deleted, and the text should be overlayed by a filled rectangle.

The button disappearing works fine, but the position of the rectangle is the position of the button. No matter if I change the values of:

```cpp
RECT rect = { 50, 120, 450, 15 };
```

```cpp
LRESULT CALLBACK MainWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uiMessage, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static HWND hWndButton;
    static HWND hWndEditBox;
    switch (uiMessage)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        hWndButton = CreateWindow(TEXT("BUTTON"), TEXT("Los geht's !"),
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
            240, 50, 120, 40, hWnd,
            reinterpret_cast<HMENU>(BTN_MAIN_BUTTON_ID),
            reinterpret_cast<HINSTANCE>(GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_HINSTANCE)),
            NULL);
        return (0);

    case WM_PAINT: {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT);
        SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(0, 0, 0));
        SetTextAlign(hdc, TA_CENTER);
        TextOut(hdc, 300, 10, TEXT("Bitte legen Sie ihr Mitarbeiterprofil an."), lstrlen(TEXT("Bitte legen Sie ihr Mitarbeiterprofil an.")));
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        return (0); }

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (wParam == BTN_MAIN_BUTTON_ID)
        {
            DestroyWindow(hWndButton);

            PAINTSTRUCT ps2;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps2);
            RECT rect = { 50, 120, 450, 15 };
            HBRUSH brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(50, 151, 151));
            GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);
            FillRect(hdc, &rect, brush);
            DeleteObject(brush);
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps2);

            int i;
            char string[20];
            for (i = 0; i< profilEinheiten; i++)
            {
                hWndEditBox = CreateWindow(
                    TEXT("EDIT"), TEXT("Edit Boxes"),
                    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
                    100, 40+(20*i), 100, 15, hWnd,
                    (HMENU)IDC_EDITBOX_TEXT,
                    (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_HINSTANCE),
                    NULL);
            }
            return (0);
            break;
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return (0);
    }
    return (DefWindowProc(hWnd, uiMessage, wParam, lParam));
}
```

Comment: You should be doing ALL of your drawing from inside of the `WM_PAINT` handler only.  Your `WM_COMMAND` handler should store any necessary info that `WM_PAINT` will need to draw the rectangle, and then `InvalidateRect()` the window to trigger a repaint so `WM_PAINT` can be called again.

Comment: In addition, *"but the position of the rectangle is the position of the button. No matter if I change the values of:..."* Although you call `RECT rect = { 50, 120, 450, 15 };` but later `GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);` overwrite the `rect` value.

Comment: Thank you for your support. 
@RitaHan-MSFT : When i comment out the ' RECT rect = { 50, 120, 450, 15}; ' the rectangle wont appear.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you now i got it. It was so easy all th time. :D Thank you.

Comment: @Arne Hi, are you doing this for learning or for a job? I'm just curious why you're interested in Winapi graphics.

Comment: @DragonautX Yes and no. Long story short: first semester at university is over. Informatics for embedded systems, so pure c. For practise im building a small managmentprogramm for a friend of mine. All still lowlevel (15 inputs, 3 formulas and like 10 outputs plus userprofil with businesslogo and filesaving). The point is: I have no Idea about the next step in learning to code. So I learn WINAPI and SQL as an extra qualification and hope its not an dead end^^.

Comment: @Arne Would you be open to talking more about your project over email? If you're doing this as a beginner, I'm impressed you found an old API like this. I can't help you. I'm doing my own personal project while I'm looking for a first job. However, I still find your idea interesting because I thought people usually study graphics for games. And also, you seem to have your project planned well. If you're interested, I can give you my email and you can contact me there.

Comment: @DragonautX I would definitely like to discuss my project. Is the mail in your blog current or are there pm?

Comment: @Arne Ya, it's on the right. It's nijobias@gmail.com. Just email me something saying that it's you (like "Hi, this is Arne." That'll work).